# Get posts from 2 categories and different taxonomies.

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I have a custom post (it's called "ait-dir-items") and 2 categories there.
On category archive page, I need to get posts which belong to 2 categories.

get posts from 2 categories

Codition.
category1= "food" on "ait-dir-item-category" (food id is 6)
and
category2= "cate" on "ait-dir-item-category" (food id is 39)
and
post_type="ait-dir-items"

I have been trying 3 ways to solve this problem.
None of them is working well. please advice me how I could fix it.

### 1st way

```
query_posts("cat=6, 39&showposts=5&post_type=ait-dir-item");
//query_posts( array( post_type=>'ait-dir-item', 'category__and' => array(6,39),         'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

while(have_posts()) : the_post();

echo $title = get_the_title();
echo $content = get_the_content();
endwhile;
```

when I put "cat=6, 39" or "'category__and' => array(6,39)", no result found.

### 2nd way

```
global $post;

$tmp_post = $post;

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'post_type' => 'ait-dir-item',
'category__and' => array(6, 39) // where 1, 2 is cat id
/*'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'ait-dir-item-special',
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => 39 // taxonomy id
)
)*/
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :

$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' );
$url = $thumb['0'];
?>

<li class="display_special_items"><img src="<? echo $url; ?>"/>"><?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
<li class="clear">
```

3rd way : relation and AND

---

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('ait-dir-item-special');
$other_custom_terms = get_terms('ait-dir-item-category');

foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
foreach ($other_custom_terms as $other_custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array('post_type' => 'ait-dir-item',
'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
array(
'taxonomy' => 'ait-dir-item-category',
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => 6
),
array(
'taxonomy' => 'ait-dir-item-special',
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => 39
),
),
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts()) {
echo '<h1 style="margin-top:10px;">'.$custom_term->name.'</h1>';

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
echo '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
endwhile;
}
}
}
```

`
I think I have little problems with these codes. it shows but duplicated and all item posts. how should I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation and couldn't find an answer for:

- Retrieving all posts, of the same custom_type that belong to custom_taxonomy1 AND also belong to custom_taxonomy2.

Example: I needed all proposals for SectorA (custom_taxonomy1), that belong to certain political party (custom_taxonomy2):

I ended up using the following query which worked for my case, you may get an idea and dapt it for yours:

```
SELECT 
wposts.ID, 
wposts.post_title, 
wposts.post_type, 
wposts.post_status,

termRels.object_id termObjectId, 
termRels.term_taxonomy_id termTaxId, 
terms.name partido

FROM $wpdb->posts wposts

INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms terms  
ON terms.term_id = $p 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms termsSector  
ON termsSector.term_id = $sector   

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy termTax 
ON termTax.term_id = terms.term_id 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy termTax2  
ON termTax2.term_id = termsSector.term_id  

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships termRels  
ON termRels.term_taxonomy_id = termTax.term_taxonomy_id  

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships termRelsSector   
ON termRelsSector.term_taxonomy_id = termTax2.term_taxonomy_id  

WHERE wposts.post_type = 'likan_planes'

AND wposts.post_title != 'Auto Draft' 
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 

AND wposts.ID = termRels.object_id 
AND termRels.object_id = termRelsSector.object_id 

ORDER BY wposts.post_title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. Please follow Wordpress's 'query_posts' reference guide for this!

Please read it here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

You will need to use this:

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(1,3), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

There are other filters there for categories you can use to your needs!